# Select statement failing SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a select statement running in a jsp against SQL Server (previously using MySql without issues).

the TOP 1 was added because otherwise SQL Server moans about order by clauses (but only when displaying a result in a jsp, not when running the query inside SQL Server Management Studio).

This query runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT TOP 1
alerts.id,
alerts.ts,
asset_firstname,
asset_lastname,
assetid,
alerttype.name,
node.zonename,
node.ipaddress,
node.zonegroupid
from
alerts, asset, alerttype, node, alertrules
where
ack=0 and
alerts.nodeid = node.id and
alerts.alerttypeid = alerttype.id and
alertrules.alerttypeid = alerts.alerttypeid and
alerts.assetid = asset.id and
alerts.alerttypeid = 1 and
asset.id=1157 and
alertrules.userid = 1
order by alerts.ts desc
```

but, when run in the jsp it returns "Column alerts.ts is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

I don't want alerts.ts aggregated or grouped by, hence the 'correct' select statement.

If I remove TOP 1 or alerts.ts desc the query returns the wrong row (earliest rather than latest record)

Converting what should be straightforward basic SQL commands so they run properly with SQL Server is proving a nightmare.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Regards
Ralph

Comment: The query works perfect;y (without the TOP 1 rubbish) when run in a JSP against MySQL and only fails if the exact same query is run against SQL Server, yet the query runs perfectly inside SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: why you put `alerts.ts = alerts.ts` on where? and after that there is no logical operator(AND /OR)

Comment: also missing space here: `asset.id=1157and`

Comment: disregard the spaces and alerts.ts = alerts.ts has been removed (an attempt to get around the error message)

Comment: @Ralph you can edit your own post and show us the correct code.

Comment: I have edited the original post and also tried Cetin's suggestion (using inner joins) the error message is the same.

Comment: Since the query runs fine from SSMS, it seems this is not the query being sent to SQL Server. Run a trace to capture the actual query.

Comment: Thanks, though I am very rusty with Eclipse and not sure how to do a trace properly (and debug doesn't seem to be working properly with breakpoints) , I will read up

Comment: @Ralph, you could trace the query actually run on the server with SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events. Either can be run from SSMS against your test server.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that helped though it shows the select never reaches SQL Server implying that it is the jdbc driver which is rejecting the select, which is bizarre (the jdbc driver is an old one because my project is old / JRE6).

Answer (score 0):

(I wrote this as an answer because as a comment would be a mess)
You are using old style joins, and have redundant checks. Maybe this could make a difference (not sure, as it seems to be a problem related to JSP):

```
SELECT TOP(1)
  alerts.id, alerts.ts,
  asset_firstname,
  asset_lastname,
  assetid,
  alerttype.name,
  node.zonename,
  node.ipaddress,
  node.zonegroupid
from alerts
 inner join asset on alerts.assetid = asset.id 
 inner join alerttype on alerts.alerttypeid = alerttype.id
 inner join node on alerts.nodeid = node.id
 inner join alertrules on alertrules.alerttypeid = alerts.alerttypeid
where ack=0 and 
alerts.alerttypeid = 1 and
asset.id=1157 and
alertrules.userid = 1
order by alerts.ts desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Cetin, though your modified select produces the exact same error (alerts.ts is invalid etc) but, as before,  only when run in the jsp and not when run in SQL Server Mgmt Studio. I may have to abandon thoughts of using SQL Server.

Comment: (blame on)I would too think of postgreSQL first if there isn't a special reason to try sql server(blame off) but I think you still look into your JSP call. This SQL wouldn't cause such an error (not in SQL server, postgreSQL, mySQL or ...).

Comment: Unfortunately had to attempt migration because of a large SQL-Server based opportunity. Error seems to be coming from the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc so it may be an issue with the jdbc driver (as the query runs without error in SQL Server Mgmt Studio). Will have to abandon for the time being. Thanks again.